# Bootstrap 4: open dropdown menu using javascript

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a simple dropdown menu which looks like this:

```
<div id="actions" class="dropdown btn-group btn btn-outline-secondary" role="group">
  <div id="actionToggle" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    toggle
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="actionToggle">
    <div class="dropdown-header">Actions ...</div>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" name="action1">Action 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" name="action2">Action 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" name="action3">Action 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

As described in the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/), it's possible to use JavaScript to open the Dropdown Menu. E.g. using the `dropdown("toggle")` method in Jquerys onDomready will open the menu when the page is loaded. The following code opens the menu as expected:

```
$("#actionToggle").dropdown("toggle");
```

But when I try to use the code inside a Jquery onclick-event handler, it does not open the menu. It's the same code and the event is fired correctly. Any ideas what is going wrong here?

```
$("#open").on("click", function() {
  $("#actionToggle").dropdown("toggle");
});
```

The html element I want to click on looks like this:

```
<div id="open">text</div>
```

Clicking the **text** should open the menu, but it does not...

I prepared a JSFiddle to play with the code: https://jsfiddle.net/3ot08j68/1/

The following libraries are used: JQuery 3.2.1, Bootstrap 4.0beta.3, Popper 1.12.9

Comment: Your Fiddle works fine for me.  Firefox 57.0.3.

Comment: Hm, not for me. Clicking on the `text` container does not open the menu, even in Firefox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change your code

```
$("#open").on("click", function() {
  $("#actionToggle").dropdown("toggle");
});
```

to

```
$("#open").on("click", function() {
  $(".dropdown-menu").toggle();
});
```

and it will work. I have updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SL_A_SH/3ot08j68/3/).

Comment: Thanks, this works. Even with `.show()` or `.hide()` it is possible. The only drawback: after clicking the **text** container, it's not possible to use the toggle button anymore. But in my case this is not relevant...

Comment: Welcome. You have to call `.show` or `.hide` separately. With `.toggle` you can do both at the same time. The toggle button does work in the fiddle.

Comment: It is not exactly what I am looking for but got me close. Thanks!